# postgresql return the first positive value from multiple columns queried

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a POstgreSQL database with multiple columns out of which only one will have a value entered.

```
    SELECT "Garden_GUID", "Municipality_Amajuba", "Municipality_Ilembe", "Municipality_Sisonke" from forms_garden
WHERE "Garden_GUID" = 'testguid';
 Garden_GUID | Municipality_Amajuba | Municipality_Ilembe | Municipality_Sisonke 
-------------+----------------------+---------------------+----------------------
 testguid    | Dannhauser           |                     | 
(1 row)
```

I wish to create a view in which the entries from those columns are colated into a single column.

I have tried:

```
CREATE VIEW municipality (GUID,funder,municipality)
AS SELECT "Garden_GUID"GUID,"Funder"funder,"Municipality_Amajuba","Municipality_Ilembe","Municipality_Sisonke"municipality
FROM forms_garden;
```

but it returns an error:

ERROR: column "municipality" specified more than once

Is there any way to query the various municipality_* columns row by row and only return the first positive entry?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`coalesce()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is what you're looking for:

```
with forms_garden as (
    select 'guid1' guid, 'Dannhauser' amajuba, null ilembe, null sisonke
    union all select 'guid2', null, 'muni2', null
    union all select 'guid3', null, null, 'muni3'
) select guid, coalesce(amajuba,ilembe,sisonke) municipality from forms_garden;
```